# Angular Breadcrumb that shows the route the user took to reach the current page

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, breadcrumbs

I started working with Angular a few days ago. I have to add a clickable breadcrumb to a site that shows to the user the route taken to land on that page. For example, the page Products can be reached from the Home and from the Shop.
If the user is in the Home and clicks on Products, this is what I want to be shown:

```
Home > Products
```

But, if he user is in the Home, clicks on Shop and then on Products, I want this:

```
Home > Shop > Products
```

Note that in the `app-routing.module.ts` Products is not a child of Shop nor Shop is a child of Home. I cannot modify the routing so every page in the entire site is a "stand-alone".

Is this possible? Do you have any advice or implementation that could possibly help me? Thanks!

Comment: I hope you're looking for this [Angular Breadcrumb based on navigation history instead of route path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697897/angular-breadcrumb-based-on-navigation-history-instead-of-route-path)

Comment: use https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive along with routerLink

Comment: use angular-crumbs  library

Answer (score 2):

Routing data is one of my favorite option to achieve things like you posted.

In your routing config array:

```
  {
    path: 'Shop',
    component: ShopComponent,
    data: { breadcrumbs: ['home'] }
  }, {
    path: 'Products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    data: { breadcrumbs: ['home', 'Shop'] }
  },
```

and you can use it inside your components like:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(d => {
      console.log(d.breadcrumbs) // ['home']
    })
  }
```

You can read more at: https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: In your example, the op must create two routes for the same component. For example: `home/products` and `home/shop/products`, is that what you meant? Or did you perhaps miss that in the question?

Comment: @Silvermind you can add just one path with many breadcrumb data inside

Comment: I know, but he wants different breadcrumbs for the same url: When the url is `/shop/products`, the breadcrumbs can be different `Home > Products` **and** `Home > Shop > Products`. Thus not depending on the route, but rather the click path.

Comment: Following the answer, for each path an identifier let's say 'path' can be set up while navigating to products from either home or shop e.g. set in local/session storage 'path : home' or path 'shop'. Next in routes array data can be defined as data : {breadcrumbs: [{path:'home', value: 'home/products'}, {path:'shop', value:'home/shop/products'}]}. then it's just the matter of getting 'path' value from local/session storage and filtering data array that comes with activated route for products